# mine .csv file is not uploading?

Tags: csv

i am using this condition to check my uploaded csv file.

```
$_FILES['csv_file']['type'] == "application/octet-stream" 
|| 
$_FILES['csv_file']['type'] == "text/plain"
```

even-though i am uploading csv file it show error i.e my csv file not uploading...

Comment: Have you tried text/csv?

Answer (score 0):

hey, did you checked the webserver has permissions to upload files to the directory your are trying to upload?

maybe a bit more of code will help here..